# I am trying tp print each line of strings with space untill newline. It says segmentation fault when i try to take 2 int inputs at the beginning

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
char str[100][100];
int i=0;
while(1){

    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str[i]);
    
    if(strcmp(str[i],"end")==0) break;
    else{
    i++;
    }
    
        
}
for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    printf("%s\n", str[j]);

return 0;
}
```

this code is working as it should. But whenever I try to get 2 int inputs at beginning, it gives a segmentation error.
Also tried with "%[^\n]c" without getting int input, still segmentation error.

```
    My input is;     
8 6
    adsasda das dasd
               dddd
 asd              sda
  dasdas
end
```

Comment: "get 2 int inputs" ... hmmm, you do never read any ints, only strings (and a newline character). Make sure you have the proper includes and pay attention to any warnings your compiler (eventually) produced.

Comment: You may want to limit your scanf too: `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", str[i]);` though this raises other problems with what to do when input is greater than 99 characters... Maybe better switch to `fgets()`?

Comment: It works when I input some strings and "end", it falls over if it reaches EOF before the input contains "end". You may need some error checking on that `scanf`.

Comment: Yes 2 int inputs at the beginning and then a new line of strings.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WiXKhchPZPjwXFNJ).

Comment: some libraries must be included: stdio.h , stdlib.h and string.h